# How are these link colors behaving with regards to the CSS Inheritance?

Tags: css, inheritance

```css
body {
  color: green;
}

.my-class-1 a {
  color: inherit;
}

.my-class-2 a {
  color: initial;
}

.my-class-3 a {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

Default link color
Inherit the link color
Reset the link color
Unset the link color

[image: This is the image of the results]

I am learning Web Development from the MDN Web Docs website and I am stuck when I am trying to understand the concept of inheritance in CSS.

There is an HTML and CSS code provided on the website and its result is also provided. The result is color of various links depending upon the classes and inheritance applied to them. I am not able to understand how the CSS is affecting the color of the links.

[Webpage from the MDN Web Docs website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#test_your_skills!)

The code and its results have already been provided to me. I just want to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

## Default link color

The `<a>` element is colored blue from the default styles that the browser has, called [*User Agent Stylesheets*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets). Most browsers have a CSS rule in their user agent stylesheet roughly equivalent to:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}
```

## Inherit the link color

Let's work top-down to better understand this case.

The `<ul>` has no explicit `color` applied to it in your CSS or in most user agent stylesheets. If we look at the [*Formal definition*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#formal_definition) of the `color` property, we can see:

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | [**Inherited**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance) | yes |

If we then refer to the [Inheritance documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance#inherited_properties), it says:

> When no value for an inherited property has been specified on an element, the element gets the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) of that property on its parent element.

Thus, for the `<ul>`, since it effectively has no explicit value set for its `color` property, it inherits from `<body>`, whose (computed) `color` value is `green`. The `<ul>` element's `color` property is *computed* to be `green`.

For the `li.my-class-1`, it again, has no explicit value set for its `color` property (from author or user agent stylesheets), so it inherits from `<ul>`, whose (computed) `color` value is `green`. The `li.my-class-1` element's `color` property is *computed* to be `green`.

For the `<a>` element inside `li.my-class-1`, it has the `inherit` value for its `color` property, which means it inherits from its parent `<li>`, whose (computed) `color` value is `green`. The `<a>` element's `color` property is thus computed to be `green`.

## Reset the link color

We can look at what the value of `initial` means from the [MDN documentation on `initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial):

> The `initial` CSS keyword applies the [initial (or default) value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) of a property to an element.

Furthermore, the [initial (or default) value is defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) as:

> The **initial value** of a [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) property is its default value, as listed in its definition table in the specification.

If we look at the [*Formal definition*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#formal_definition) of the `color` property, we can see:

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | [**Initial value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) | `canvastext` |

Thus, `<a>` element's `color` value is `canvastext`.  This is a [System Color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/system-color), [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/system-color#canvastext) as:

> `CanvasText`
> Text color in application content or documents

For "typical" set ups, this would be equivalent to `black`. Thus `color: initial` is equivalent to `color: black` and hence why the `<a>` element is colored `black`.

## Unset the link color

We can look at what the value of `unset` means from the [MDN documentation on `unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

> The `unset` CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) if not.

If we look at the [*Formal definition*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#formal_definition) of the `color` property, we can see:

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | [**Inherited**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance) | yes |

Thus, the `color` property of the `<a>` element follows the same behavior as `color: inherit`, as specified in the *Inherit the link color* section detailed previously.